# Creating an Express API from MongoDB server automatically

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express

I have a pretty large MongoDB server running on my local machine, I know how to create an API using Express & Node.js and know how to use routes, etc. But I only know how to add new data to a route using the POST method. My database has tens of thousands of entries in different collections and so it would be impossible to add them all manually.

I wanted to know if there was a way to quickly convert my entire mongodb local database into an API with Express so I can access it client-side from my React.js application.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish. Could you describe a scenario with some sample data?

Comment: @codemonkey basically, I have a database in my local instance of mongodb (running on port 27017), it has a collection called "people" with some data in it. I basically want to copy all the data in the collection "people" (in the JSON format) to the express API route "/people" so I can GET it using fetch.

Comment: That's understood. What I am trying to figure out is what you mean by *My database has tens of thousands of entries in different collections and so it would be impossible to add them all manually* Add them manually? Add them where?

Comment: @codemonkey oh, by that I meant. I know how to create an empty express API server but I don't know how to add all the data in the Mongodb collection to the express API server. I know how to add single values manually to the express API server using the POST request but I want to add every object in my mongodb collection to that specific route automatically without having to add each one manually via the POST request